# Find Character Name programmatically

Tags: php

This is a bit of weird question and I'm not sure this will be at all possible, but I am curious to see.

I was wondering if there is any way, preferentially using php that you can find the name of a character. For example I have a form on a page and someone types `€` into the input, when they submit the form, the form returns "Euro". If some types `!` into the box, the page returns "Exclamation".

Other than trying to search for a possible solution I have done little else towards this. I have a few ideas on how I could use a case statement etc and evaluate the character symbol myself which involves a potentially large case statement.

This is really for my knowledge.

Comment: You can make an array of result which consist the possible outputs of the symbols or can store that value within database too

Comment: there's no PHP function that I know of, but you could load something like http://www.utf8-chartable.de/ into a database/memcached etc. & then perform a lookup

Comment: Your best bet will be to use the Unicode character database to search for information about a character, which includes its official name. However that will be something like "EXCLAMATION MARK".

Comment: I think it can be achieve only via mapping.

Comment: I think give the calibre of people who have commented so far it certainly seems that some kind of database implementation would be necessary to achieve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There doesn't seem to exist a such API, but after some search I found out that the Unicode Consortium provides a giant XML database referencing the character hexadecimal values and their description.

The file can be found here: [ucd.all.flat.zip](http://www.unicode.org/Public/UCD/latest/ucdxml/)

For every `char` tag, you'll find a `cp` attribute (hex value of the character) and a `na` attribute (description of the character).

I hope it will help!

Comment: This definitely seems like the best approach. Many thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You can get character name with `IntlChar` class from `intl` extension.

```php
$char = new \IntlChar();
echo $char->charName('€'); // EURO SIGN
```

Answer (score -1):

Php doesn't have any factory made methods for returning the name of those characters. But You can create one your self using an array which contains the symbol and the symbol name ,then you can do a search in the array and show the symbol name. See the example below i made using php. Thanks :)

```
  <?php
   $examplecharacter  = '$';
   $array = ['$' => 'dollar' , '&' => 'ambersand'];
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if($key == $examplecharacter){

     echo $value;


     }
    }

   ?>
```

Comment: I think that author asked for some build-in or lib solution. Your answer is too obvious.

Comment: No need to loop through the array. Check check if key exists and use it to lookup the name.

Comment: Why you give a -1 for the answer. Give an explanation please.  :) The author of the question is confused and he asked for a solution for showing the symbol'name ..

Comment: .He didn't mention anything about buildin or lib @ValeryStatichny

Comment: @JijoJohn, Do you really believe, that the author with 2k score expects for your solution ?

Comment: @ValeryStatichny 2k score doesn't matter.  Knowledge matters..   I don't have enough time to spend answering questions in stackoverflow. I only have few minutes everyday to answer the questions. If i have enough time i can score more than that..

Comment: @JijoJohn, 2k score proves that a man knows such obvious things.

Comment: @JijoJohn as mentioned in my question I know I could create a `case` or an `array` or any other variation in order to achieve my goal. However, I was interested if there were an inbuilt way or a community approved solution for this. I appreciate the effort.

Comment: @TheHumbleRat i really appreciate your comment :)

Comment: @ValeryStatichny so you are saying the people with 0 stackoverflow score and the people who doesn't have a stackoverflow account are stupids .. That's not right man ..Everybody learns something new everyday even a guy with million points learn something everyday. Knowledge is infinite and questions are infinite ..That's why every day stackoverflow is getting tons of questions. :) sorry if this comment is rude.. Have a good one